# Fold expression for a parameter pack with comma operator: How to add additional parameters when expanding the pack?

Tags: c++, c++20, variadic-templates, fold-expression, compile-time-type-checking

I want to design a compile-time-string class `CTString` that can e.g. be constructed from a parameter pack of string literals. This works using a comma-fold-expression (for this toy example, I tried to avoid the use of any system headers to make it self-contained):

```
template<unsigned N>
struct CTString
{
    char m_chars[N + 1U];

    template<unsigned... Ns>
    constexpr CTString(const char (&...s)[Ns])
    {
        auto* p{ m_chars };
        ((p = CopyN_(s, Ns - 1U, p)), ...);
        *p = '\0';
    }

    // copy size characters and return one past last copy:
    constexpr char* CopyN_(const char* pFrom, unsigned size, char* pTo)
    {
        for (auto i{ 0U }; i < size; ++i)
            *(pTo++) = *(pFrom++);
        return pTo;
    }
};

template<unsigned... Ns>
constexpr auto concat(const char(&...s)[Ns])
{
    return CTString<(0U + ... + (Ns - 1U))>{s...};
}

constexpr auto cHelloWorld{ concat("Hello", "World") };
static_assert(cHelloWorld.m_chars[9] == 'd');
static_assert(cHelloWorld.m_chars[10] == '\0');
```

Now I have an additional use case to insert a separator after each literal. How can I expand/fold the parameter pack to insert e.g. the literal `"|"` after each element of the pack?
This is my feeble attempt that fails because the expression `(s, "|")...` does not work: The comma   here just leads to the left operand being discarded:

```
template<unsigned... Ns>
constexpr auto concatWithSeparator(const char(&...s)[Ns])
{
    return CTString<(0U + ... + Ns)>{(s, "|")...};
}
// Compilation error:
constexpr auto cHelloCommaSeparated{ concatWithSeparator("Hello", "World") };
```

I can work around this problem by introducing a helper class and having the compile-time-string also accept packs of the helper class in its constructors. But I was wondering whether there is neat idiom that I am missing.(I did read and re-read this great article, but to no avail:
[C++20 idioms for parameter packs](https://www.scs.stanford.edu/%7Edm/blog/param-pack.html)

The code that compiles is here:
[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/76b1sETqY)
Un-comment the last line to see how it fails.

Comment: Do you want the result to be `"Hello|World|"` or `"Hello|World"`? The first case is easy by reusing your concat function, see here: https://godbolt.org/z/Gr3YYbr48

Comment: @joergbrech: For the time being, "Hello|World|" is all I am looking for. Your solution is very nifty and avoids the addtional helper class, I was contemplating- thanks!
However, I am still intrigued to see a solution based purely on parameter pack expansion ...

Comment: I don't understand: My solution uses parameter pack expansion, there is a `...` in line 38 of the godbolt link. I don't think there are more parameters to expand? You create an expression of `s` and then expand this expression to every element of the pack. As an alternative to calling `concat` twice, you can just replace `(s, "|")` in your attempt with `concat(s, "|").m_chars`: https://godbolt.org/z/P5qcxo5vr. BTW on an unrelated note: You can make all functions `consteval`.

Comment: @joergbrech: Your solution is great! And I shall probably use it. But it exploits the fact my class happens to have a char[N+1] field, which is sort of an implementation detail. 
So I was wondering, whether there is a solution that expands a parameter pack (s...) to another pack (s[0], "|", s[1], "|", s[2], "|", etc.).

Comment: Ah ok, I think I understand. I don't think there is a simple and easy solution. I posted an answer with the best that I could come up with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple and pragmatic solution would be to re-use your `concat` function:

```cpp
template<unsigned... Ns>
constexpr auto concatWithSeparator(const char(&...s)[Ns])
{
    return CTString<(0U + ... + Ns)>{concat(s, "|").m_chars...};
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hzv5qv6no.

---

If you want to know how to interleave the parameter pack with the seperator `|`, I don't think there is a *simple* solution. One option is to first create a tuple, whose elements are the parameter pack interleaved with the seperator:

```cpp
auto tup = std::tuple_cat(
    std::tuple<const char(&)[Ns], const char(&)[2] >(s, "|")...
);
```

As a next step, you would need to translate the tuple back to a parameter pack, which in turn can be passed as argument(s) for the `CTString` constructor.

You could do this by forwarding the tuple to a templated helper function using `std::index_sequence`. With C++20, you have templated lambdas so that the helper function could be a lambda defined in the body of `concatWithSeparator` that you immediately evaluate:

```cpp
template<unsigned... Ns>
constexpr auto concatWithSeparator(const char(&...s)[Ns])
{
    auto tup = std::tuple_cat(
        std::tuple<const char(&)[Ns], const char(&)[2] >(s, "|")...
    );
    return [&]<std::size_t ... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        return CTString<(0U + ... + Ns)>{std::get<Is>(tup)...};
    }
    (
        std::make_index_sequence<2*sizeof...(Ns)>{}
    );
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/W1jhcrGc5

---

A slightly more readible version of the second solution would be to use [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply):

```cpp
template<unsigned... Ns>
constexpr auto concatWithSeparator(const char(&...s)[Ns])
{
    return std::apply(
        [&](auto const&... args){ return CTString<(0U + ... + Ns)>(args...); },
        std::tuple_cat(std::tuple<const char(&)[Ns], const char(&)[2] >{s, "|"}...)
    );
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/q3GshYx5a

Comment: You can use `std::tie` to simplify creating the 2-tuples.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot transform a pack `arg0, .., argN` into `arg0, sep, .., argN, sep`.

As alternative, you might add extra constructor to make extra works by element of pack:

```
struct SeparatorTag{};

template<unsigned N>
struct CTString
{
    char m_chars[N + 1U];

    template<unsigned int NSep, unsigned... Ns>
    constexpr CTString(SeparatorTag, const char(&sep)[NSep], const char (&...s)[Ns])
    {
        auto* p{ m_chars };
        ((p = CopyN_(s, Ns - 1U, p), p = CopyN_(sep, NSep - 1, p)), ...);
        *p = '\0';
    }
    // ...
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v4Y3qKKrj)

Comment: Is your _cannot_ a hunch or do you have a sort of proof? This kind of pack expansion _is_ possible when folding with e.g. operator+:
`template<unsigned... Is> constexpr auto sumAndExtraOne() { return (0U + ... + (Is + 1U)); }`
`static_assert(sumAndExtraOne<1, 2, 3, 4>() == 14U);`
So the comma-operator appears to be special in that respect?!

Comment: You don't really interleave element in your sum, you actually have `(Init @ ... @ func(Is))`. With property of `+` (with numbers) (associativity, commutativity, ...), it behaves as if it is interleaved, but it is not.